# I have passed __all__ in fields of meta class and still i am getting back only one field. suggest a better way to fix it I want all the field there

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have included the serializer as well as the views.py, I am new so it might be possible that i made a very silly mistake here, which I am not able to figure out, please review this code and make me understand how to resolve this issue.

serializer.py

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
    
    def to_representation(self, value):
         return value.name

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('name')

class SaloonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    services = ServiceSerializer(read_only = True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Saloon
        fields = (
            'name', 'services'
        )
```

Here in the field of SaloonSerializers I have tried multiple things like only name field but still  if get just one output which i have attache at the end of this post.

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def saloon_list(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        saloons = Saloon.objects.all()
        serializer = SaloonSerializer(saloons, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    time = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Saloon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank=False)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "services": [
            "Cutting",
            "Shaving",
            "Eye Brow",
            "Waxing",
            "Facial massage"
        ]
    },
    {
        "services": [
            "Cutting",
            "Shaving",
            "Facial massage"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please show the (relevant) models?

Comment: class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    time = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Saloon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank=False)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Hi Sir, I have edited the question, Please Help I am new here dont know much about it

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with a `ModelSerializer`: a simple serializer does not care about a `Meta`, and will only serialize items for which you have specified a serializer field yourself.

You thus should rewrite this to:

```
#                    ModelSerializer ↓
class SaloonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    services = ServiceSerializer(read_only = True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Saloon
        fields = (
            'name', 'services'
        )
```